# 22.04 TTY not working

Tags: tty

I have a 2-channel thermometer (Mastech 6514) that sends temperature data from a coffee roaster to a graphical monitoring program called Artisan (https://artisan-scope.org/). Artisan read the data when I entered the following string into its set-up */dev/ttyUSB0*. After upgrading to 22.04, Artisan no longer sees the data, and I cannot find anything about how to fix this by doing a Google search.

Comment: make sure the user artisan uses is part of the group used by /de/ttyUSB0. It will be  `dialout`.  `groups` to show currently active groups for the active user or `groups {user}` for {user}

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I checked. However, I've found the solution. Apparently, 22.04 automatically loads a module to support braille teletype users. It's BRLTTY. Earlier, I thought it might be this, but because I'm somewhat vision impaired, I thought it was BRITTY. By using synaptic to remove this module, Artisan was again able to see the data stream.

Comment: cool but do make it an answer :) this might stump others.

Answer (score 2):

22.04 automatically loads module BRLTTY to support braille teletype users. By using synaptic to remove this module, Artisan was again able to see the data stream.